# Display flex has no influence - ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, display

I want to show items as flex but still it is showing like a column. What am I doing wrong here?
This is my  component :

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./Listing.css";

const ProductComponent = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products);
  const renderList = products.map((product) => {
    const { id, title, image, price, category } = product;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div key={id} className="item-box" >
          <Link to={`/product/${id}`}>
            <div className="image-box">
              <img src={image} alt={title} />
            </div>
            <div className="detail">
              <div >{title}</div>
              <div >$ {price}</div>
              <div >{category}</div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <>{renderList}</>;
};

export default ProductComponent;
```

This is the css file of this component:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    
}

.item-box{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 380px;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px; 
}

img{
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

And finally this is my App.css:

```
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

I wanna show the items as flex (from left to right) but it is like a column though I defined "display:flex"[image: This is the picture of current]

Comment: You require flex-direction in one of the css blocks, check out this docs
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the array and outputing multiple containers. Each container is display-flex but the problem is that they all have only one child. Move the `map` inside the container:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    { products.map((product) => {
      const { id, title, image, price, category } = product;
      return (
        <div key={id} className="item-box" >
          <Link to={`/product/${id}`}>
            <div className="image-box">
              <img src={image} alt={title} />
            </div>
            <div className="detail">
              <div >{title}</div>
              <div >$ {price}</div>
              <div >{category}</div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the style of `.container` just add `flex-direction:coloum`

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

If you want the column in center, then you can append `justify-content:center` & `align-items:center` as well.